# Windows Phone 8 don't added pdf files at build

Tags: pdf, build, windows-phone-8

Comparing the source and the console log I saw that all pdf files aren't adding. For this reason (obviously) the app crash when I call some pdf file. Another files (.png, .xml, .html, ...) don't have any problems.

What is the reason? I need add to another location?

[image]

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to set build action for your *.pdf files to "Content". It works in my project.

Comment: Select your files in solution, open context menu->properties->Build action.